# PHP sharpness convolution martix

Tags: php, image, matrix, gd, convolution

I'm using a **[convolution matrix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php)** for sharpness in **PHP GD** and I want to change the sharpness **"level"**.

Where would I **make changes** to this if I want to make it **more or less sharp**?

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('pic.jpg');

$matrix = array(
  array(0, -1, 0), 
  array(-1, 5, -1), 
  array(0, -1, 0)
);

imageconvolution($image, $matrix, 1, 0.001);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: see http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/unsharp.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking on http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/imageproc/page2.asp

There are lots of examples on the web, but as a rule of thumb you may try these params first in GIMP or PS or any other editor that has this function (image convolution is pretty common)

Comment: Perfect, there was a formula I was looking for

Comment: @MarkLalor Could you please share this formula?

Answer (score 2):

What you really needed to do was use this formula

[image]

Where k = sharpness level.

Comment: should k be always negative on the third formula?