# I am looking for normal image sharpening matrix to use in PHP image convolution

Tags: php, matrix, gd

I am looking for a convolution matrix to use to sharpen images, searched round the Internet the ones I got did not sharpen the image or over sharpened or sharpened and left blurs on the image.

Note: I have also compressed the images at `imagejpeg($tmp_min,$folder.$file,75))` after imagecopyresampled in compression before upload. These are the closest I have gotten to, please if I can get a matrix that can get me Instagram image sharpness I would appreciate it.

```
$matrix = array(
   array(0, -1, 0),
    array(-1, 11, -1),
    array(0, -1, 0),
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588607/php-sharpness-convolution-martix?rq=1

Comment: @astax i have seen that post before it oversharpens the image not really what i expected i tried increasing the middle number still blurish